# How to match elements in a ClassName with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a random number of elements (which can be divs, headers and so on) with a particular class.
I need to split that class into maximum 4 words but I can't get any result.

***I want to let people custom this plugin. The first number is the number of column, and the second number is the max width desired to reset this plugin***

I'm coding this way:

//HTML

```
<!--
X stands for the foo number
Y stands for the boo number
-->

<div class="foo-X-boo-Y></div>
<div class="foo-X-boo-Y></div>
<div class="foo-X></div>

<!--and many other elements-->
```

//JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '[class*=boo-]' ).each(function() {
        var boo = $( this );
        var n = parseInt( boo.attr( 'class' ).match( /boo-(.*)/ )[1] );
        var booReset = boo.attr( 'class' ).match( /foo/ );
        var numb = boo.attr( 'class' ).match( /foo-(.*)/ );
    });
});
```

the variable n returns the X number.
the variable booReset returns the ["foo"] or null value.
the variable numb returns ["foo-Y", "Y"] and I only need the Y number.

I need to parse the Y integer.

I tried by doing the same thing as the n variable but the console returns "TypeError: boo.attr(...).match(...) is null". Why?

I tried in other way like:

/.*?<=reset/ returns null
/(.*$)?<=reset/ returns null

anything I do is always NULL!

Is there a way to section the class-name according to hyphens?

foo-X-boo-Y

should be

foo, x, boo, y

and then work with these four variables?

here the fiddle with the entire JS
http://jsfiddle.net/dcdeiv/yAn5K/3/

Comment: This does not sound like the best way to be doing whatever it is you're trying to do. If you can explain why you need this, I'm sure someone will be able to give you a much better code pattern to follow.

Comment: Do you have any control over HTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you want to parse out the X and Y numbers, and do some logic based on them. If so then you need to do a string split:

```
var tokens = "foo-1-boo-2".split("-");
// => ["foo", "1", "boo", "2"]

var tokens = "foo-42".split("-");
// => ["foo", "42"]
```

Then you can handle the cases using the global function parseInt().

As for HTML, don't forget that divs can have many classes. You can handle that case with another string split (on " " this time).

Answer (score 0):

How about that: Split the class names by the `-`character and filter out any non-numeric values.

Like so:

```
$( '[class*=boo-]' ).each(function() {
      var boo = $( this );
      var className = boo.attr("class");
      var numbersInClassName = $.grep(className.split("-"),function(item){ 
          var num = parseInt(item);
          return !isNaN(item);
      });
      console.log(className + ": " + numbersInClassName);
});
```

Here's a modification of your original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yAn5K/7/

Comment: Well, then just use the last value of the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `String.split(delimiter)`

```
var pieces = $(this).attr('class').split('-');
console.log(pieces);
> ['foo', 'X', 'boo', 'Y']
```

So now you have an array (`pieces`) of all the words in the classname.

Answer (score 0):

parsing the class seems a bit strange. Would it be an option to use data attributes?

e.g. `<div class="foo-X-boo-Y" data-X="valX" data-Y="valY"></div>`

```
var n = $(".foo-X-boo-Y").data("X")
```